# upload file jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload, plugins, upload

hi my name is luca! im just a beginner with jquery and i completely stuck on uploading a file(or more) with jquery.
Im actually trying to post a form (with input fields like "title","text"..plus the file upload one) with jquery and i can get all of the input file posted correctly in the $_POST array..but i have problems with the $_FILES one.

I'm using the Multiple File Upload plugin and as I read in the documentation i Just add the multi class to my file input element.

here it follows jquery little code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submit").click(function(){  
    var title=$("#title").val();  
    var article=$("#article").val();  
    var images=$("#image").val();     
    var dataString="title="+title+"&article="+article+"images[]="+images;  

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "php/newPost.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      cache: false,  
      success: function(html){ //here i handle the received content  
      }  
    });     
  });  
});
```

It is sending correctly everything except for the input file element..so please let me know how should i do..
I dont want to use iFrames and flash plugins =)
thanks
Luca

Comment: Indent your code!, see how much easier it is to read formatted code? :)

Answer (score 0):

The first question that needs to be answered is do you have the following attribute applied to your form tag?

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: yes i do but newPost.php tells me that there's an Undefined index: images where i try to handle the posted file (foreach($_FILES['images']['name']))

Comment: Per the post @ codingforums.com/showthread.php?p=798122 - Due to JavaScript's security model, it's not possible to do a "true" Ajax file upload. You either have to use an iframe element on the page or one of the alternative methods using Flash.  Look at the following jQuery Plugin as it is a recommended alternative: http://www.uploadify.com/demos/